# Under construction page dosen't load - 302 redirect from htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, using

I want to redirect all my traffic to a "under construction" ( coming soon) page but the style of page dosen't load. I think I need to redirect all traffic to /under-construction/ folder but if I try that I receive a loop redirect error ( too many redirects )

I use this rewritre code using .htaccess to redirect all traffic except my ip.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^5.xx.xxx.xx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/under-construction/index\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://gopal.net.cn/under-construction/index.html [R=302,L]`

What I need to do to work?

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: You say the styling of your page does not load. Does that mean that your HTML file itself does load?

Comment: The page need to looks like photo 1 and now it's look like photo 2.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YswA0GuA7NtswYgreSD-CoypS9MmTTo6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Photo 2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/15GVFZeczjK_JGYk86Ut5z9skCslQRTBk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

That was the solution:

```
    # MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^5.x.xxx.xxx
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/under-construction/index.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|php|js) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /under-construction/index.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

This code line was needed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|php|js) [NC]` . Without it the js, php, css dosen't load.

Answer (score 0):

May you just want to redirect only the HTML pages, but not the images and css. Then use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^5.xx.xxx.xx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/under-construction/index\.html$
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ http://gopal.net.cn/under-construction/index.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I use this, the page is load corectly if i accest directly page URL but now there are no redirect from main page to the under construction page. :(

Comment: What is the URL of main page?